# How do I search for a file in a directory using the terminal?

Tags: shell, file, search, terminal, directory

I'm trying to locate a file in a huge directory with a lot of other subdirectories and files.

What's the easiest way to find a given `file_name.x` in such directory tree?

Answer (score 2):

You could try

`find path_to_huge_directory -type f -name "file_name.x"`

This will search through all files in that directory and its subdirectories.

Comment: Would you please accept my answer? (First off all time - very excited :) )

Comment: This use of quotes is very strange.  For consistency, you should use one of `find "/path/to/huge/directory" "-type" "f" "-name" "file_name.x"` or (preferred) `find /path/to/huge/directory -type f -name file_name.x`  Either of those invocations runs exactly the same command.  The only reason you might use quotes on the filename is if you are trying to prevent a glob expansion (eg `-name "*_name"`)